# VuePress: How to modify the markdown content

Tags: vuepress, markdown-it

VuePress (v1) provides this API to access the page context: https://v1.vuepress.vuejs.org/plugin/option-api.html#extendpagedata

I can access these properties but I can't change the value of `_content` for instance.

I would like to modify (replace some regexp) the markdown before it get's rendered by Vue (an even before it's get parsed by the markdown parser).

Maybe it makes more sense to do it with a markdown-it plugin using the [chainmarkdown](https://v1.vuepress.vuejs.org/plugin/option-api.html#chainmarkdown) API but I don't know how exactly. But the question is more how to write a plugin for [markdown-it](https://github.com/markdown-it/markdown-it) which can modify the content before even parsing, because I need the raw text.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one markdown-it plugin that allows you to do exactly that by defining regular expressions: https://www.npmjs.com/package/markdown-it-regexp